# Laptop restarts with Critical Process Died BSOD

Tags: windows-11, bsod, crash

so recently I started having some issues with my laptop. It happens randomly that, the screen becomes unresponsive, after a few seconds, it glitches, and laptop turns off with either 'Critical process died' or 'Unexpected system error' bsod. It did happen once in a while in the past too, but it's more frequent now, after one day I noticed the back panel just below the screen on one side is a little broken. There was no screw at that side, so I unscrew one of the middle ones and put it on the side which seemed broken (to support it a little). After that, after some angle, if I moved my lid back, my laptop won't turn on. So I reverted back the screw, and now it's working as it did (with the bsod ofc).

The bsod happens randomly, it's not as if it happens when I'm working on some application that take up more resources. Sometimes it happens when it is idle too. Sometimes it'll happen 3-4 times in a row, and other times it won't happen for 2-3 days.

My laptop is Lenovo ideapad 3i, running on windows 11 home. It had 8 GB of Ram but I did a upgrade to 12GB. It has an ssd of 256GB (C:) with a HDD of 1TB. It has an integrated graphics of 4GB, Intel UHD graphics.

I turned the Intel Virtualization off from BIOS, I thought it solved the problem but it again happend after 2 days, 4 times in a row.

I've not updated the BIOS since it came in 2020, (it came with windows 10, these errors never happened on windows 10)  I'm a bit scared in doing so. Can it happen that this might be the problem? Also, I've not updated any driver (except those that came with the automatic windows updates)

I'm attaching cpu z screenshot, and a video of how the glitch and bsod process happen.

[image]

Video: https://drive.google.com/file/d/12Kgdr1pchQR_uPrIqml5Zdb1Vvz4jQ_m/view?usp=drivesdk

PS: attaching the dmp files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/135IJNUmciSzVZkGAyooVC0ek_eXNhlhT

Comment: Is a .dmp file created?

Comment: I've attached the dmp files

Comment: Nothing more than... I like the UI and prefer to stay updated with microsoft updates (I didn't do a clean install, I upgraded from windows update)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it sounds like a hardware issue which is hard enough to trouble shoot hands-on let alone via Q and A over the internet.

Comment: Flex in a laptop can definitely contribute to breaking poor connections and causing faults like you describe. I would recommend trying to find a replacement for the screw you're missing, and then taking care to leave the laptop completely still when using it. Treating it more like a desktop may allow it to be more useful for you in these later years of its useful life. Use an external keyboard and mouse, and possibly an external monitor as well. The less the laptop flexes and moves while you use it, the better it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Flex in a laptop can definitely contribute to breaking poor connections and causing faults like you describe.

I would recommend trying to find a replacement for the screw you're missing, and then taking care to leave the laptop completely still when using it. Treating it more like a desktop may allow it to be more useful for you in these later years of its useful life.

Use an external keyboard and mouse, and possibly an external monitor as well. The less the laptop flexes and moves while you use it, the better it will work for you.